# Using Git Bash on Windows, how do I checkout a branch that begins with a Unicode character?

Tags: git, unicode, git-branch, git-bash

I am using git bash.

I created a branch, did some changes and committed. When I tried to push, it gives me:

> error "refpath does not exist".

I then checkout to other branch and retried to checkout to my branch but it says

> error: pathspec 'tabViewComponent' did not match any file(s) known to
>   git.

I did `git branch`, and it gives me branch name like this:

[image]

Comment: It did'nt let me checkout in my branch so i checked out in new branch form the last commit which saved my work and let me checkout out in new branch 
git checkout -b newbranchname commit-sha-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to checkout to that branch and rename it, before pushing it, to do so:
*with the numeric pad*

```
git checkout ALT+96tabViewComponent
git branch -m ALT+96tabViewComponent:tabViewComponent
```

On **ALT+96** don't forget the plus sign, if you got " **`** " as the output, you forgot the plus sign (The Unicode character should be *invisible*)

*Edit:* **ALT+96** means `START OF GUARDED AREA` and is a control character, you can also get the same character with **Alt 0150**

If you are a java person:

```
System.out.println("->\u0096<-");
```

And just copy the deadspace between the arrows of your output

[Reference](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/96/index.htm)

Comment: Could you edit the question to add a hyperlink to some reference explaining what `ALT+96` means?

Comment: There you go, took me some time to find the requested reference :)

Comment: You need to type the plus sign with the numeric keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

The branch name starts with the Unicode character ['START OF GUARDED AREA' (U+0096)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/96/index.htm)  that is difficult to distinguish from the ordinary dash character (`-`), only slightly wider on the font I am using.

Ways of entering Unicode characters at the command prompt differ by platform. You could copy it from the page linked above (or the command below) or use the compose sequence appropriate for your platform.

```
git checkout –tabViewComponent
```

[On Windows, entering Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Microsoft_Windows) is done by default with

> Unicode characters can then be entered by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, pressing the <kbd>+</kbd> on the numeric keypad, followed by the hexadecimal code – using the numeric keypad for digits from 0 to 9 and letter keys for A to F digits – and then releasing <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

This is not a particularly friendly name for a branch because of all the trouble necessary to check it out and the confusion it will lead to if someone tries to use a leading dash. I *strongly* recommend renaming it to remove the leading U+0096.

Answer (score 0):

Taking reference from https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+0096, I see the name of the branch contains `–` at its start. can you try `git checkout –tabViewComponent`. Not sure if it a valid branch name.